# Adding another layer of grouping to entity framework linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'd like to group cities by country, then by continent.

My location model looks like this:

```
public class Location
{
    [Key]
    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Continent { get; set; }
}

public class Group<T, K>
{
    public K Key;
    public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

And I currently group just by country like this:

```
groupedLocations = db.locations.OrderBy(d => d.Name).GroupBy(d => d.Country).OrderBy(d => d.Key);
```

I've since added 'Continent' to the location model, and would like to do another layer of grouping by this field, but not sure how.  My first thought was to try:

```
groupedLocations = db.locations.OrderBy(d => d.Name).GroupBy(d => d.Country).GroupBy(d => d.Continent).OrderBy(d => d.Key);
```

but it looks like you can only have one level of grouping?

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

My groupedLocations is declared as:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Location>> groupedLocations { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with the following code:

```
var groupedByContinent = locations.GroupBy(x => x.Continent);

var groupedByCountry = groupedByContinent.Select(group =>
    new
    {
        Key = group.Key,
        NestedGroup = group.ToLookup
                        (result => result.Country, result => result.Name)
    });

var dictionary = groupedByCountry.ToDictionary
    (result => result.Key, result => result.NestedGroup);

groupedLocations = dictionary;
```

groupedLocations is declared as:

```
public Dictionary<string, ILookup<string, string>> groupedLocations { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by multiple columns using anonymous types:

```
groupedLocations = db.locations.GroupBy(d => new { d.Continent, d.Country })
                               .OrderBy(d => d.Key.Continent)
                               .ThenBy(d => d.Key.Country);
```

Comment: I get an error at the "ThenBy" line: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,Project.Models.Location>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,Project.Models.Location>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Higher up in my code I'm actually converting Locations ToList() as well which may affect this

Comment: You have to change `groupedLocations` type to make it work (type it using implicit typing, because of anonymous type).

Comment: Made an edit to show how groupedLocations should be typed, what do I need to set it to?